# Short to int automatic promotion

Tags: java

```
public class Yikes1 {
    public static void go(Long n) {
        System.out.println("Long "); // printed
    }

    public static void go(Short n) {
        System.out.println("Short "); // don't know why isn't this printed
    }
    public static void go(int n) {
        System.out.println("int "); // printed
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        short y = 6;
        long z = 7;
        go(y); 
        go(z);
    }
}
```

How does the short value got converted to int before it prints the output?

I thought widening works only when the dataype-short is not available so it looks for next available data type which is int in this case but however short datatype is defined here so how come the automatic promotion happening?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `short` and `Short` aren't the same thing. Try it with a method taking `short n`.

Comment: in your case auto-boxing is not preferred..

Answer (score 9):

The binding sequence works as follows:

1. Exact match (Ex.  `int--> int`)
2. Promotion (Ex. `int --> long`)
3. Autoboxing/Unboxing (Ex. `int --> Integer`)
4. Varags (Ex. `int --> int...`)

Answer (score 5):

Okay, when there's no method, which accepts `short`, there's 2 options: autobox it into `Short` or cast to integer. [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) states, that the second option in prefered:

> Method invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> 1. an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> 2. a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> 3. a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> 4. a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference
>      conversion
> 5. an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening
>      primitive conversion.

What you expect here is `a boxing conversion`, but what you get is `a widening primitive conversion`.

You can read more about boxing [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to correctly understand the relation between `short` and `Short`.